# Custom timepicker with jQuery and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I build a custom timepicker with jQuery and bootstrap.
It's almost finished, but 1 "nice to have detail" is missing and I'm stucked getting to the result.

It should follow this rules:

1. Select the time on click
2. Only related times are possible to select.
3. Only 1 time range at once is possible (e.g. 09:00-11:00 works but can't pick another time range)
4. Disabled times are not possible to pick and if they are between a possible time range, only the range before or after disabled are allowed.
5. It should be possible to click the start time and the end time and if there are no obstacles in between, the times between should be selected as well.

1-4 are working but I'm stucked on point 5.

So what I want to achieve is that if I click on `13:00-14:00` and `15:00-16:00`, `14:00-15:00` should be selected automatically if allowed by above rules.

```js
    $('.time-cal .time-btn').on('click',function(){
        if($('.time-cal .time-btn.btn-success').length == 0)
        {
            $(this).not(".btn-danger").toggleClass('btn-success');
            $(this).not(".btn-danger").toggleClass('btn-light');
        }else{
            if($(this).hasClass('btn-light'))
            {
                if($(this).next().hasClass('btn-success') || $(this).prev().hasClass('btn-success'))
                {
                    $(this).not(".btn-danger").toggleClass('btn-success');
                    $(this).not(".btn-danger").toggleClass('btn-light');
                }
            }else{
                let next = $(this).next();
                let prev = $(this).prev();
                
                if(!next.hasClass('btn-success') || ! prev.hasClass('btn-success'))
                {
                    $(this).not(".btn-danger").toggleClass('btn-success');
                    $(this).not(".btn-danger").toggleClass('btn-light');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="time-cal col-lg-6 col-12">
                                <label>Pick times</label><br>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-danger" data-start="07:00" data-end="08:00" disabled="">07:00 - 08:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-danger" data-start="08:00" data-end="09:00" disabled="">08:00 - 09:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="09:00" data-end="10:00">09:00 - 10:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="10:00" data-end="11:00">10:00 - 11:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-danger" data-start="11:00" data-end="12:00" disabled="">11:00 - 12:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="12:00" data-end="13:00">12:00 - 13:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="13:00" data-end="14:00">13:00 - 14:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="14:00" data-end="15:00">14:00 - 15:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="15:00" data-end="16:00">15:00 - 16:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-danger" data-start="16:00" data-end="17:00" disabled="">16:00 - 17:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-danger" data-start="17:00" data-end="18:00" disabled="">17:00 - 18:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="18:00" data-end="19:00">18:00 - 19:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="19:00" data-end="20:00">19:00 - 20:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="20:00" data-end="21:00">20:00 - 21:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="21:00" data-end="22:00">21:00 - 22:00</button>

                                <div class="form-group">

                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            
                            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I posted an answer, but it might not need your requirements, rereading those now. I thought the setup was nice and started working on how I thought I would handle it haha. But you don't want to allow the selection to include disabled boxes? I will leave the answer as is now and await your feedback first :)

Comment: @Me.Name Well - thanks for the nice feedback :)
Your way of selecting is pretty much what I wanted, but for my needs it's crucial that a selection is not possible further than the next disabled time.
As background information why I need it that way: This is for a reservation tool... so f.e. if you reserve a table in a restaurant, you can't leave and come back later to that table :)

Comment: Thanks for that background info, it makes perfect sense that way and it is nice to know they context and why :) I have changed the code to only allow one 'timeblock'  at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-edit altered behaviour based on the comments.
At startup each time'button' is divided into a specific timeblock so buttons in the same timeblock can be quickly handled together (there might be some additional/other behavioral requirements when reselecting)

```js
const 
        disabledClass = 'btn-danger',
    selectedClass = 'btn-success',
    notselectedClass = 'btn-light',        
    timeButtons = $('.time-cal .time-btn'),
    enabledButtons = timeButtons.not('.' + disabledClass ),
    timeBlocks = [];    
    
    timeButtons.each((index,btn)=>{btn.enabled=!$(btn).hasClass(disabledClass); 
        if(btn.enabled){
        if(index===0 || !timeButtons[index-1].enabled){         
          timeBlocks.push([]); //new timeblock
        }
        btn.timeBlock = timeBlocks[timeBlocks.length-1];
        btn.timeBlock.push(btn);
      }
      prevEnabled = btn.enabled;
        btn.index = index;btn.selected=false;       
      btn.setSelected = sel => {if(btn.selected===sel)return; btn.selected=sel;
            $(btn).toggleClass(notselectedClass,!sel).toggleClass(selectedClass,sel);}
      });
    

         
enabledButtons.click(function(){          
         if(this.selected){
                //deselect and make sure times in this block after this button are deselected too
                        this.timeBlock.filter(btn=>btn.index >= this.index && btn.selected).forEach(btn=>btn.setSelected(false));
            return;
         }
                
        //deselect other timeblocks
        enabledButtons.toArray().filter(b=>b.timeBlock !== this.timeBlock).forEach(b=>b.setSelected(false));
        
        //check if there are other selected
        const selected = this.timeBlock.filter(b=>b.selected);
        if(selected.length === 0)
          this.setSelected(true); //no other buttons selected, simply select
        else{
          //select range withint the timeblock
          let from = selected[0].index, to = this.index;
          if(from > to)
            [from,to] = [to,from];
          for(let i = from;i<=to;i++)
            timeButtons[i].setSelected(true);
        }       
        
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="time-cal col-lg-6 col-12">
                                <label>Pick times</label><br>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-danger" data-start="07:00" data-end="08:00" disabled="">07:00 - 08:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-danger" data-start="08:00" data-end="09:00" disabled="">08:00 - 09:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="09:00" data-end="10:00">09:00 - 10:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="10:00" data-end="11:00">10:00 - 11:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-danger" data-start="11:00" data-end="12:00" disabled="">11:00 - 12:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="12:00" data-end="13:00">12:00 - 13:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="13:00" data-end="14:00">13:00 - 14:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="14:00" data-end="15:00">14:00 - 15:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="15:00" data-end="16:00">15:00 - 16:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-danger" data-start="16:00" data-end="17:00" disabled="">16:00 - 17:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-danger" data-start="17:00" data-end="18:00" disabled="">17:00 - 18:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="18:00" data-end="19:00">18:00 - 19:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="19:00" data-end="20:00">19:00 - 20:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="20:00" data-end="21:00">20:00 - 21:00</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs time-btn btn-light" data-start="21:00" data-end="22:00">21:00 - 22:00</button>

                                <div class="form-group">

                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            
                            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: awesome - 1 minor point for improvement, would be perfect if you can do the range from bottom to top as well.... (e.g if you select 14-15 first and 12-13 afterwards and all buttons between become selected 2)

Comment: An alteration was made